Can i connect the code of other components to the other components without touching the original code? Angular coding in Vs code
I want to connect my footer media query code to the About me code without any changes in the whole project, is there any possible way to do that?
I tried putting the footer media query in my about me components but the whole footer is moved out in other components. I expect that if i put the footer query in the about me the footer in about is the one will change, but not the other components.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
